# How to fill a datagridview with data depending on the value in a database column

Tags: sql, datagridview, visual-foxpro

Let's say I have a database table 'USAGE' like below:

```
MACHINE     WEEK        HOURS       PIECES
A           2018-12     1           2
B           2018-12     3           4
A           2018-13     12          1
B           2018-13     2           5
A           2018-15     6           6
B           2018-15     2           2
C           2018-16     2           1
D           2018-17     4           22
B           2018-17     3           9
A           2018-18     1           8
E           2018-18     4           4
D           2018-13     2           4
```

and I want to show the data in the datagridview as follows:

```
MACHINE     2018-12     2018-13     2018-14     2018-15     2018-16     2018-17     2018-18
A           1H 2P       12H 1P                  6H 6P                               1H 8P
B           3H 4P       2H 5P                   2H 2P                   3H 9P
C                                                           2H 1P
D                       2H 4P                                           4H 22P
E                                                                                   4H 4P
```

In visual foxpro this was pretty simple.

```
this.edType      = 1
this.ehCols      = 20
this.ehStartval  = date()+ 7
```

This created 20 columns with the different weeks in the header. Then with a command like below you were done:

```
this.ehKeyFld    = "iif(usage.hours > 0 and usage.pieces > 0,STR(usage.hours,4) + 'H ' + STR(usage.pieces,3)+'P','')"
```

Now I want to do the same thing but I like to show the data in a datagridview.

If I do something like this:

```
select machine, iif(week='2018-12',str(hours,4) + 'H' + str(pieces,3) + 'P','') as '2018-12', IIF(week='2018-13',str(hours,4) + 'H' + str(pieces,3) + 'P','') as '2018-13', IIF(week='2018-14',str(hours,4) + 'H' + str(pieces,3) + 'P','') as '2018-14', IIF(week='2018-15',str(hours,4) + 'H' + str(pieces,3) + 'P','') as '2018-15', IIF(week='2018-16',str(hours,4) + 'H' + str(pieces,3) + 'P','') as '2018-16', IIF(week='2018-17',str(hours,4) + 'H' + str(pieces,3) + 'P','') as '2018-17', IIF(week='2018-18',str(hours,4) + 'H' + str(pieces,3) + 'P','') as '2018-18' from GCCTEST.dbo.usage
```

I get the following output:

```
machine 2018-12 2018-13 2018-14 2018-15 2018-16 2018-17 2018-18
A       1H  2P                      
B       3H  4P                      
A               12H  1P                 
B               2H  5P                  
A                               6H  6P          
B                               2H  2P          
C                                       2H  1P      
D                                               4H 22P  
B                                               3H  9P  
A                                                       1H  8P
E                                                       4H  4P
D               2H  4P
```

I am looking for a command in SQL that can fill the datagridview in the way I want, that is every machine one row with data in the correct column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accept things are easier with VFP. However, saying datagridview, I would assume you meant C# and this could also be done in C# in many ways. With SQL you could also use "PIVOT". ie:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE([MACHINE] VARCHAR(1), [WEEK] VARCHAR(7), [HOURS] INT, [PIECES] INT);

INSERT INTO @table(MACHINE, WEEK, HOURS, PIECES)
VALUES('A', '2018-12', 1, 2),
    ('B', '2018-12', 3, 4),
    ('A', '2018-13', 12, 1),
    ('B', '2018-13', 2, 5),
    ('A', '2018-15', 6, 6),
    ('B', '2018-15', 2, 2),
    ('C', '2018-16', 2, 1),
    ('D', '2018-17', 4, 22),
    ('B', '2018-17', 3, 9),
    ('A', '2018-18', 1, 8),
    ('E', '2018-18', 4, 4),
    ('D', '2018-13', 2, 4);

SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT MACHINE, WEEK, STR(HOURS, 4)+'H'+STR(PIECES, 3)+'P' AS data
    FROM @table
    ) AS source
PIVOT(
     MAX(data)
     FOR WEEK IN([2018-12], [2018-13], [2018-14], [2018-15], [2018-16], [2018-17], [2018-18])
     ) AS mypivot;
```

However, you wouldn't like to hardcode all those columns in SQL. Check for "dynamic PIVOT". Here is a sample from Northwind data:

```
DECLARE @COUNTRY NVARCHAR(MAX) = '' , @cTotal NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT  @COUNTRY = @COUNTRY + COALESCE(QUOTENAME(Country) + ', ', '')
FROM    Customers
WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT *
                 FROM   [Orders] AS [o]
                 WHERE  o.[CustomerID] = Customers.[CustomerID] )
GROUP BY Country;

SET @COUNTRY = LEFT(@COUNTRY, LEN(@COUNTRY) - 1);

SELECT  @cTotal = @cTotal + COALESCE('Coalesce('+QUOTENAME(Country) + ',0) +', '')
FROM    Customers
WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT *
                 FROM   [Orders] AS [o]
                 WHERE  o.[CustomerID] = Customers.[CustomerID] )
GROUP BY Country;

SET @cTotal = LEFT(@cTotal, LEN(@cTotal) - 1);

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQL = 'SELECT * , ' + @cTotal + ' AS TOTAL FROM 
    (
        SELECT  oe.EmployeeID, oe.LastName, oe.ShipCountry AS CO,
                OD.Quantity * OD.UnitPrice AS QU
        FROM    (
                  SELECT  EmployeeID, LastName, ShipCountry
                  FROM    (
                            SELECT DISTINCT
                                    ShipCountry
                            FROM    Orders
                          ) o ,
                          Employees
                ) oe
        LEFT JOIN Orders O ON O.EmployeeID = oe.EmployeeID AND
                              [oe].[ShipCountry] = [O].[ShipCountry]
        LEFT JOIN [Order Details] OD ON OD.OrderID = O.OrderID 
    ) AS T
    PIVOT(SUM(QU) FOR CO IN (' + @COUNTRY + ')) AS PVT
    ORDER BY 1';

EXEC(@SQL);
```

Comment: Datagridview as in VB.NET. Looking at this example I realize I don't know much about sql. I'm going to have a go with it, but if there is a way to do it in VB.NET that would give me another option. Example: [link](https://i.imgur.com/XFnomTR.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

My solution:
I have one database with the descriptions of the machine in tblMachines and I have one database with the usage of the machines in tblUsage.
On my windows form I have one datagridview Dgv_4 and one Combobox1

```
' Separate class to do the sql command
Public SQL As New SQLControl
Private Dgv_4Query As String = $"m.id,m.listorder,m.prio,m.machine as 'Machine',m.weekuren as 'Hour/wk', week, STR(u.HOURS, len(u.HOURS))+'h_'+STR(u.PIECES, len(u.PIECES))+'p' as data FROM {GV.DB}tblMachines m "
Private Dgv_4Join As String = $"LEFT JOIN {GV.DB}tblUsage u on m.machine = u.machine "
Private Dgv_4Pivot As String = ""
Private EmptyQueryStringDgv_4 As String = ""
Private TotNumWeeks As Integer = 15

Private Sub DataGridViewForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MdiParent = Main
    ' Create headers for datagridview with dates and weeknumbers starting with current week
    Dim WeekNumber As Integer = DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Date.Now, FirstDayOfWeek.Monday, FirstWeekOfYear.System)
    ' First part of the pivot command
    Dim PivotString As String = $"PIVOT (MAX(data) FOR week IN("
    Dim endline As String = ","
    ' Middle part of the pivot command
    For i As Integer = 0 To TotNumWeeks
        If i = TotNumWeeks Then
            ' Last part of the pivot command
            endline = ")) as mypivot"
        End If
        PivotString = PivotString + $"[{Date.Today.Year}-{WeekNumber + i}]{endline}"
    Next
    Dgv_4Pivot = PivotString
    EmptyQueryStringDgv_4 = $"SELECT * FROM (SELECT {Dgv_4Query}{Dgv_4Join}) as source {Dgv_4Pivot} order by prio"
    LoadDataGridView1()
    ' Load combobox with current week
    ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
    ComboBox1.Text = $"{Date.Today.Year}-{WeekNumber}"
End Sub

Public Sub LoadDataGridView1(Optional ByVal QueryString As String = "", Optional ByVal Parameter As String = "")
    Dim dgvclass As New DataGridViewClass()
    Dim dname As DataGridView = Dgv_4
    Dim SelectRow As Integer = 0
    If QueryString = "" Then
        ' Default query
        QueryString = EmptyQueryStringDgv_4
    End If
    ' Use the sql command to request the data
    dgvclass.FillDataGridView(QueryString, Parameter, "Normal") = dname
    ' Hide column(s)
    dname.Columns(0).Visible = False
    dname.Columns(1).Visible = False
    ResizeGrid.ResizeGrid(dname, dname.Width)
End Sub
```

This will show and load the datagridview starting from current week and with a combobox you can choose different weeks:

```
Private Sub ComboBox_Drop(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.DropDown
    Dim ac As ComboBox = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
    If Me.ActiveControl Is ComboBox1 Then
        ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
        ' Fill combobox with a range of weeks to chose from
        For i As Integer = -1 To 1 Step 1
            For j As Integer = 1 To 52
                Dim num As String = j.ToString
                If Len(num) < 2 Then
                    num = $"0{num}"
                End If
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(Date.Today.Year + i & "-" & num)
            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ' Create headers for datagridview with dates and weeknumbers
    Dim result As String = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
    Dim PivotString As String = $"PIVOT (MAX(data) FOR week IN("
    Dim endline As String = ","
    Dim weekadd As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To TotNumWeeks
        If i = TotNumWeeks Then
            ' Close string
            endline = ")) as mypivot"
        Else
            ' Check year limits
            If (Convert.ToInt32(Strings.Right(result, 2)) + i) > 52 Then
                ' Change year and week
                weekadd = 0
                result = $"{Convert.ToInt32(Strings.Left(result, 4)) + 1.ToString}-01"
            End If
        End If
        PivotString = PivotString + $"[{Strings.Left(result, 4)}-{(Convert.ToInt32(Strings.Right(result, 2)) + weekadd).ToString("D2")}]{endline}"
        weekadd = weekadd + 1
    Next
    Dgv_4Pivot = PivotString
    ' Run query without pivot, seems to prevent insert columns on the right
    LoadDataGridView1($"SELECT {Dgv_4Query}{Dgv_4Join}")
    ' Run query with pivot to fill datagridview with new weeks
    LoadDataGridView1($"SELECT * FROM (SELECT {Dgv_4Query}{Dgv_4Join}) as source {Dgv_4Pivot} order by prio", "")
End Sub
```

Example of output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7HYo.jpg

Comment: OK. Probably you missed the VB code I have given. It doesn't need to pivot in SQL server (pivot in SQL server doesn't really add any benefit). Doing that client side is easier and code is more maintainable IMHO.

Comment: Yes, I did miss that VB code. I think that it is a better way to go about it, without the pivot in sql server and coding on the client side. I will have a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I too find it more difficult to do in SQL and .Net lacks the dynamism of VFP < g > you might still solve this with some custom pivoting the data yourself. A pivot is generally called as a cross tab in VFP. Practically it is about summarizing the data and then distributing to columns where one column of values (here machines) are transposed to columns. In your sample, data is already summarized, actually no need to use MS SQL's pivot. IMHO it is OK to get that data and create the cross tab locally in a datatable since you have just about 20-25 columns (weeks) and maybe at most a thousand machines. Here is the code for sampling (code is converted from C# using telerik code converter - note: I used MS SQL server base query from yesterday just to mimic that your data would come from MS SQL):

```
Private Sub Main()
    Dim sql As String = "DECLARE @table TABLE([MACHINE] VARCHAR(1), [WEEK] VARCHAR(7), [HOURS] INT, [PIECES] INT);

INSERT INTO @table(MACHINE, WEEK, HOURS, PIECES)
VALUES('A', '2018-12', 1, 2),
    ('B', '2018-12', 3, 4),
    ('A', '2018-13', 12, 1),
    ('B', '2018-13', 2, 5),
    ('A', '2018-15', 6, 6),
    ('B', '2018-15', 2, 2),
    ('C', '2018-16', 2, 1),
    ('D', '2018-17', 4, 22),
    ('B', '2018-17', 3, 9),
    ('A', '2018-18', 1, 8),
    ('E', '2018-18', 4, 4),
    ('D', '2018-13', 2, 4);

    SELECT MACHINE, WEEK, HOURS, PIECES FROM @table"
    Dim tbl As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Using con = New SqlConnection("server=.\SQLExpress;Trusted_Connection=yes")
        con.Open()
        tbl.Load(New SqlCommand(sql, con).ExecuteReader())
        con.Close()
    End Using

    Dim weeks = 20
    Dim weekStart = 12
    Dim year = 2018
    Dim result As DataTable = New DataTable()
    result.Columns.Add("Machine", GetType(String))
    For i As Integer = 0 To weeks - 1
        Dim week = $"{year}-{i + weekStart}"
        result.Columns.Add(week, GetType(String))
    Next

    Dim lst = tbl.AsEnumerable()
    Dim machines = lst.[Select](Function(l) l.Field(Of String)("Machine")).Distinct().OrderBy(Function(l) l)
    For Each machine As String In machines
        Dim row = result.NewRow()
        row("Machine") = machine
        For i As Integer = 0 To weeks - 1
            Dim week = $"{year}-{i + weekStart}"
            Dim weekValue = lst.SingleOrDefault(Function(t) t.Field(Of String)("WEEK") = week AndAlso t.Field(Of String)("Machine") = machine)
            row(week) = If(weekValue Is Nothing, "", $"{CInt(weekValue("Hours"))}H {CInt(weekValue("Pieces"))}P")
        Next

        result.Rows.Add(row)
    Next

    Dim f As Form = New Form()
    f.Controls.Add(New DataGridView With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill, .DataSource = result})
    f.Show()
End Sub
```